# For a complex matrix $A$ that preserves the inner product, prove that $A^*=A^{-1}$

Tags: matrices

I was interested in the proof of the following:

> Let $A$ be a matrix which preserves the inner product; i.e. $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle Ax,Ay\rangle$
>
> Prove that $A^*=A^{-1}$

I have read that the two statements are "alternate definitions" of a unitary matrix. Hence, one must imply the other. However, I can't find a proof online. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

We have

$$\langle x,y\rangle=\langle Ax,Ay\rangle\iff \langle x,y\rangle=\langle A^*Ax,y\rangle\iff \langle (A^*A-I)x,y\rangle=0\;\forall y$$
hence we conclude that $(A^*A-I)x=0,\;\forall x$ and then $A^*A-I=0$ which means
$$A^*=A^{-1}$$